# Как использовать Блок «Поделиться»,чтобы можно было поделиться и фотографией?

Tags: ya-share2

Как использовать Блок «Поделиться»,чтобы делясь появилась ссылка с  фотографией?

Comment: разве там в параметрах нельзя было прописывать url, которым делишься?

Comment: Я новичок.Не разобрался.Вроде всё указываю,но не отображается.Значит где-то допускаю ошибку.Помогите,если можно на примере.Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Дак вы приведите код, как вы пытаетесь это сделать. Сложно найти ошибку, если не видишь код.

Comment: Вот код. Нужно вставить data-image. Куда я не знаю. Если знаете Вы,то буду рад Вашей помощи.<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"></div>